# New Ubuntu install on new laptop is unable to find wifi adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

I am on a new laptop, new to Linux but here is the information:

Laptop: HP Pavilion
Ubuntu Version: 20.04

I typed lspci -v in the terminal and I think this is the relevant part of the output:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
DeviceName: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.2 Combo Adapter (MU-MIMO supported)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
I/O ports at e000 [disabled] [size=256]
Memory at fea00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Going to settings > wifi it says "No wifi adapter found". I can confirm that the wifi was working on the Windows boot, but I have replaced it entirely with Ubuntu now.

EDIT: So I have managed to connect to the WIFI now by going to additional drivers and choosing to use open source drivers. I don't know how optimal it will be though compared to the proprietary drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the internet and run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

and reboot.

This will install a driver for this adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when upgrading from Ubuntu 19.10 to Ubuntu 20.04, where suddenly my wifi adapter was no longer recognized (Dell Precision m2800).

After spending hours trying to install drivers and tweak settings, etc, I decided to open the laptop and reseat the wi-fi card. That fixed it. Apparently, moving my laptop around I must have knocked it in a way that unseated the card.

Good luck